# How do you alphabetize the order of Strings using Arrays.sort()?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, alphabetical, alphabetical-sort

I'm working on review problems for an exam and one of the problems ask that I alphabetize book titles in order. I am asked to ignore the word "The", if it appears in the beginning of a title. My question is, is there a way to sort the title order of books while ignoring "The" using Arrays.sort()?

Originally I put the books in an Array list called **books** and then applied:

```
Arrays.sort(books);
```

It worked but only to some extent because it wouldn't ignore "The". Instead is it better to do:

```
public class booktest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter the title of your book: "); // The Great Gatsby
    String book = IO.readString();
    if(book.substring(0, 3).equalsIgnoreCase("the")){
        book = book.substring(4);
    }
    System.out.println(book); // Output: Great Gatsby
```

And then compare the first letters of each book to output the ascending order?

I was wondering if there was a simpler way to go about this. Any clues or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-

Comment: I believe you are expected to print the book names as they were originally. So storing them without the "the" is not a good idea. You should write a `Comparator` instead.

Comment: I don't think there is any way for you to avoid doing some sort of processing on the book titles that you have in your String Array prior to sorting.  It's likely that you will also need to do checks for "a", "the" and any other prefixed words that prevent sorting books in librarian order.

Comment: @assylias thanks for the link!

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yeah, the problem asks to print out the original book titles. I'm going to learn how to use that. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @GMLewisII sounds like work.. the suggestions below seem to figure out and solve the problem. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be slightly careful.

1. `book.substring(0, 3)` throws a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` for strings of length less than 3.
2. A title that begins `"the"` does not necessarily begin with the word "The". It could begin with "There" for example.

If you are using Java 7 or an earlier version, I would make a separate method like this

```
private static String noThe(String b) {
    return b.length() >= 4 && b.substring(0, 4).equalsIgnoreCase("the ") ? b.substring(4) : b;
}
```

Then you can use

```
Arrays.sort(books, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String b1, String b2) {
        return String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(noThe(b1), noThe(b2));
    }
});
```

In Java 8, you do not need a helper method as you can just do

```
Arrays.sort(books,
            Comparator.comparing(b -> b.length() >= 4 && b.substring(0, 4).equalsIgnoreCase("the ") ? b.substring(4) : b,
                    String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER));
```

Full example (Java 8 version):

```
String[] books = {
            "The Great Gatsby",
            "The Witches",
            "Persuasion",
            "It",
            "Therapy"};
Arrays.sort(books,
            Comparator.comparing(b -> b.length() >= 4 && b.substring(0, 4).equalsIgnoreCase("the ") ? b.substring(4) : b,
                    String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(books));
```

The output is

```
[The Great Gatsby, It, Persuasion, Therapy, The Witches]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't consider the error possibilities. I'll try to be more careful. As for the code, I'll study it and try to implement it on my own, thanks again!

Comment: @elbertkim No problem. `It` and `Therapy` are good test cases, as these are likely to cause errors. Don't forget you can accept the answer that you like the most (check the tick next to the answer).

Comment: I don't know how to tag but I hope this works. I'm learning a lot today. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a custom Comparator which does the trick. You can use any one based on the SDK.

Comparator using lambda expression

```java
Comparator<String> c1 
        =  (String o1, String o2)->ignoreThe(o1).compareTo(ignoreThe(o2));
```

Comaprator for Java SDK v < 8

```java
Comparator<String> java7Comparator = new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return ignoreThe(o1).compareTo(ignoreThe(o2));
    }
};
```

Code Snippet

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class BookComparison {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Comparator using lambda expression
        Comparator<String> javaLambdaCompare 
            =  (String o1, String o2)->ignoreThe(o1).compareTo(ignoreThe(o2));

        //Comaprator for Java v < 7
        Comparator<String> java7Comparator = new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return ignoreThe(o1).compareTo(ignoreThe(o2));
            }
        };

        ArrayList<String> books = new ArrayList<String>();
        //Add from source
        books.add("Robinson Crusoe by Daniel Defoe");
        books.add("Gulliver’s Travels by Jonathan Swift");
        books.add("David Copperfield by Charles Dickens");
        books.add("The Scarlet Letter by Nathaniel Hawthorne"); 
        books.add("The Moonstone by Wilkie Collins");
        books.add("Three Men in a Boat by Jerome K Jerome");

        //pass any of the Comparator as an argument to sort
        books.sort(javaLambdaCompare); 
    }
    public static String ignoreThe(String book){
        if(book.length()>=3 && book.substring(0, 3).equalsIgnoreCase("the")){
            book = book.substring(4);
        }
        return book;
    }
}
```

The result sorted list:

- David Copperfield by Charles Dickens,
- Gulliver’s Travels by Jonathan Swift,
- The Moonstone by Wilkie Collins,
- Robinson Crusoe by Daniel Defoe,
- The Scarlet Letter by Nathaniel Hawthorne,
- Three Men in a Boat by Jerome K Jerome

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! I haven't learned about Lambda expression yet but I'll use this opportunity to learn more about it on my own.